# targeting specific class attribute without repeating

Tags: javascript, class-attributes

I wanted to make a game where you figure out a color combination by clicking on squares. The problem is I cant figure out how to make each individual square change colors instead they all change at once. I looked at several w3schools and mozilla tutorials but they didnt have what i was looking for.

```js
let box = document.querySelectorAll('[data-box]')
for (i = 0; i < box.length; i++) {
  box[i].addEventListener('click', () => {
    box.forEach(color => {
      color.style.backgroundColor = "green"
    })
  })
}
```

```css
div.box {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  margin: 10px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="box" data-box></div>
<div class="box" data-box></div>
<div class="box" data-box></div>
<div class="box" data-box></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

They all change at once because you're using `box.forEach()` to instruct them to all change at once.

You should only change the box that is the `target` of the current click event:

```js
let box = document.querySelectorAll('[data-box]');
for (i = 0; i < box.length; i++) {
  box[i].addEventListener('click', (e) => {
      e.target.style.backgroundColor = "green";
  })
}
```

```css
div.box {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  margin: 10px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="box" data-box></div>
<div class="box" data-box></div>
<div class="box" data-box></div>
<div class="box" data-box></div>
```

Alternatively, iterate over the boxes and invoke the event listener on the current iteration target:

```js
let box = document.querySelectorAll('[data-box]');

box.forEach(b => b.addEventListener('click', () => b.style.backgroundColor = 'green'));
```

```css
div.box {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  margin: 10px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="box" data-box></div>
<div class="box" data-box></div>
<div class="box" data-box></div>
<div class="box" data-box></div>
```